# I want to add a link to comment count in this wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

[This image is showing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYyMR.png)

This is WordPress paid theme "Soledad." I Want to add a comment form link to the text "Comment" for every page. Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you expect us, to just do the work? Share your current code, so we may help you.

Comment: It is not a custom made website. This is a WordPress website. It contains various PHP files, I don't know which one to edit.